# Bind HashTable/Map to Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hashmap

I have a C# background and I'm pretty new to Java. Trying to port my windows application to Mac using Java.

The issue I have is how to bind a HashTable that contains a class to a JTable so that the variables in the key show up in the JTable. In C# WPF it's very easy, just binding GridView.ItemSource to dictionary.keys. But in Java it seems much more complicated. Here is what I have so far:

```
Map<Files, String> files = new HashMap<Files,String>();

public class Files {
       public Files(String files, String duration, String status) {}
                   }

public void AddFiles(String addfile, String addduration, String addstatus, String path){
            files.put(new Files(
                    addfile, addduration, addstatus), 
                    path);
            }
```

In C# the class would look a little different, but I can just do GridView.Itemsource = files.Keys and voila, it all shows upp perfectly. How can I achieve something similar in Java?

I know that JTable can use a multidimensional array to load the values, so I am right now trying to load the values of HashTable into `Object[][] tableData` and then use:

```
String[] columnNames = {"File","Duration", "Status"};
final JTable table = new JTable(tableData, columnNames);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the variables inside the class "Files" inside the HashMap "files".

I know there is: `.getKey().getClass()` but I still haven't been able to load the multidimensional array with the values of the class "Files" inside the HashMap.

Comment: you would like to get Keys within the HashMap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a tableModel extending from the base class `AbstractTableModel`. In here you'll have to override the appropriate methods (your IDE will point them out), the most important one being `getValueAt()`.

Override this one in a fashion similar to:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
     switch (columnIndex) {
     case 0:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getValueX; // Change to however you'd like to call a single value from your map
     case 1:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getValueY;
     case 2:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getValueZ;
     default:
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
     }
}
```

You can call your model with your data as a parameter. Afterwards, use this model as an argument to your JTable and you should be fine.

Comment: can you please be more clear? What do you mean call the model with my data as a parameter? When would I call it?

Comment: When you create your JTable, pass it your model (which you define elsewhere) as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `keys` of a `HashMap` using `HashMap.keySet()` method.

This will return a `Set` of the key objects, which you have stored in your `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<Files, String> yourHashMap = new HashMap<Files, String>();
Set<Files> keys = yourHashMap.keySet();
```

Once you have got the set, assuming that you have the `DefaultTableModel` set to your `JTable`, you can do,

```
for(Files f : keys) {
   yourDefaultTableModel.addRow(new String[]{f.files, f.duration, f.status});
}
```

NOTE:

Its always *better* to use a **class** which overrides `equals()` method & which is **immutable**  to use as `HashMap` key.

Overriding `equals()` will avoid keys being overwritten incase of [Hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29), and making a class **immutable** doesn't make the value associated with the key **orphan** (since the key will not change once its created)

So I suggest using `HashMap<String, Files>` instead of `HashMap<Files,String>` if you feel making `Files` class immutable breaks its purpose.